# Restricted camera view

Tags: camera

Why is the rendered area (the red rectangle) in the pic below so small?

How do I resize it to fit the entire viewport?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> will remove the render border and render every part of the viewport. To set it again use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>, but if you are in camera view, it will be constrained to the camera's view bounds.